# How can I display a wall of `#` characters using GUI?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a room in Python where the top, bottom, right, and left walls are filled up with `#` characters. Here's my attempt:

```
from gui import Gui

class Room:
    """The room has a width and height, a character to draw, and color."""

    def __init__(self, width, height, c,
            fore_color, back_color):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.c = c
        self.fore_color = fore_color
        self.back_color = back_color

    def draw(self, gui):
        gui.draw_line(self.c, 0, 0, self.width - 1, 0,
             self.fore_color, self.back_color)

    def main():
        room = Room(gui.get_width(), gui.get_height(), "#","WHITE", "BLUE")
```

The output of the wall of the room suppose to be like this:

[image]

Comment: What's `gui` inside your import?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your example code but this is what I would try for the rectangle

```py
print("#" * w + ("\n#" + " " * (w - 2) + "#")*(h-2) + "\n" + "#" * w)
```